# Display image for link

Tags: php, drupal, hyperlink

Below piece of code that i use in template.php of drupal to display the facebook link

```
$links = array();
        $links['facebook'] = array(
              'title' => 'facebook',
              'href' => "http://facebook.com",

              'html' => TRUE,
          );
```

this display the title"facebook" on the site but i want facebook icon instead of title what piece of code in need to add to it..??

Comment: I don't suppose you can share the code that parses the array and creates the link?

Answer (score 0):

if you were to change it to `<img src='http://www.ok.gov/ltgovernor/images/Facebook-icon.png' />` then it might work but if the other php is puting the title here `<a title=$links[''title]` rahter then `<a>$links['title']</a>` then it won't work.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why OP would link out to the Oklahoma Lt. Governor's site for a facebook icon.

Comment: don't matter where it comes from it's just an example +it is the fb icon